# StraightTalk Wifi Calling with ATT iPhone 6

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, sim, wifi-calling

If you have experience with using an ATT iPhone on the StraightTalk, please state which iPhone + IOS version you have tested with StraightTalk.  If there were any changes required to the ATT iPhone configuration: the steps required to reproduce wifi calling would be of interest.

Can I expect wifi calling on the StraighTalk network to work with a SIM unlocked ATT iPhone 6?

Comment: i'm sure this would be better asked of the supplier.

Comment: Even though OP can ask their carrier for support, that doesn’t make this off-topic here. Also, low cost carriers cut costs by not offering good (or any) human support other than self help online.  I’ll point to this carriers self help in an answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is their compatibility page:

- http://www.straighttalkbyop.com/

They say any unlocked GSM phone works, so the only problem with an iPhone from AT&T service would be a carrier lock. Be sure you confirm AT&T has unlocked your device if you’re not sure it’s unlocked - but that seems to be something you have already done from your description.

So yes, you should expect your device to work perfectly with a StraightTalk SIM and service. Apple baseband is very well tested with hundreds of GSM carriers and since apple ships so few devices comparable to other vendors, they tend to get carriers to fully support any and all versions of iOS on all hardware models.