# Wifi Calling Configuratble Provisioning Items

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, wifi-calling

What carrier specific software setting must be configured to properly enable wifi calling?  Clarification: I understand that wifi calling must be enabled, however, this is not a carrier specific software setting and is the same for any carrier.

Answer (score 1):

Zero configuration is needed on iOS past turning it on or turning it off.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203032

All configuration on iOS is about extending the calling that works on your iPhone to other non phone devices.

Hit up [your carrier if you can’t turn on WiFi calling](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361260/straighttalk-wifi-calling-with-att-iphone-6).